# Google Spreadsheets-Find top five values in a column

Tags: google-sheets

I have a column in a Google Spreadsheet where each cell contains a single word. I need to find the top five most occurring words. Does anybody know how I can achieve this?

Comment: *Top five occurrences of each unique word*? How would a occurrence qualify for the *top five* then? Or do you mean top five most occuring words?

Comment: You are correct, changed my question in line with your comment, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=query(A:A,"select A,count(A) group by A order by count(A) desc limit 5 label A 'Word',count(A) 'Frequency' ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Start with a 'helper' column. In an unused column to the right use this formula in the row containing the first word then fill down.

```
=if(countif(A$2:A2, A2)=1, countif(A$2:A, A2), "")
```

Now you can build your list of 'top five most occurring words' with this formula in another column.

```
=index(A$2:A, match(large(B$2:B, row(1:1)), B$2:B, 0))
```

[Linked sample worksheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XqvdoDYg13YPNdKCsIsjy2UIpQZsWNDcW0Ke60gzMUE/edit?usp=sharing)